# Displaying binary on LCD

Tags: lcd, character-lcd, binary

Hi I am doing a home project to make a simple calculator. I plan on using a encoder for the number and arithmetic inputs and I want to display it on an LCD. I plan on having a 16:4 encoder where 0 to 9 would be my numbers and 10 to 14 would be +, -, *, /, and =, respectively, The problem is I am unsure of how to get the LCD to take this binary numbers and display the corresponding character. I have been trying to google binary to ASCii converter/decoder and search it on texas instruments but to no avail. Is there a specific why to do this? Thanks

Comment: "LCD" is not specific enough to answer this.

Comment: What LCD display are you using exactly and what MCU will you use to program your calculator?

Answer (score 1):

ASCII "0" is hex 0x30, or decimal 48 - just OR your encoder output with 0x30 to get the ASCII digit.

Comment: Ok so from what I looked up 0x is just for notation purposes for hex. So you want me to OR my encoder outputs with the hex equivalent, but I am unsure of how to do this could you elaborate more?

Comment: The top four bits of the character you send to the LCD will be 3 (0011), and the lower four bits will be the four bits from your encoder.  I'm assuming that your LCD display wants ASCII.  If not, we need more info on your display.